# Date field default value must need to be Null in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using Sugar Professinal 6.4.4.

The problem i am facing is this, that when i create a custom field of type Date (Not DateTime) and don't assign a default value to it. Then when i use that custom field in Edit and Detail View of a module and save the record without assigning any value to that field in Edit View, Sugar after saving the record automatically assign the current date to that field which gets visible in Detail View. Though in database the value for that custom field is still Null.

How can i stop this defualt behaviour of automatically assigning current value to that custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the default value as NULL, you can set the default value in fieldset as

```
 ['display_default']= "''";
```

If you want to save the current date, use this

```
['display_default']='now';
```